# quickbook query not working c#

Tags: c#, quickbooks

I am developing a asp.net c# project and now i am trying to sync it with quickbook. I was trying to query on timeactivity of quickbook using queryservice

```
var timeactivityQueryService = new QueryService<TimeActivity>(serviceContext);

var timeActivitiesWithCondition= timeactivityQueryService.Where(ta => ta.Hours == 6);
```

timeActivitiesWithCondition is empty but I have timeactivity with 6 hours in sandbox. It shows inner exception

```
 "ValidationException was thrown."
Invalid Query
```

How can i query on time activity correctly. It will be nice to hear from any of you. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer docs. Only fields marked as filterable can be queried.

https://developer.intuit.com/docs/api/accounting

hour is not filterable so you can not add filter on hour.

Comment: ok i had no idea about filterable properties thanks a lot. i will try it another way